# Is it possible to use Entity Framework with SharePoint?

Tags: entity-framework, sharepoint

Are there any compatibility issues when using EF with SP? 
Is there any particular version of EF that needs to be used with SP-2010/2013?

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using?  The answer is yes, there are many things you can do.  You can turn Entity Framework into SharePoint list(s) and vice versa. Just google it there are many tutorials out there.

Comment: @jmb.mage : Will do thanks for the reply.